# How do I add a guard ring to a matrix in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/), a matrix A has n rows and m columns, and I want add a guard ring to matrix A. That guard ring is all zero.

What should I do? Use Reshape? But the element is not enough to make a n+1 m+1 matrix.

Or etc.?

Thanks in advance

###### I mean an extra ring of cells that always contain 0 surround matrix A.Basically there is a Matrix B has n+2rows m+2columns where the first row and columns and the last row and columns are all zero,and the rest of it are same as matrix A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362489/how-do-i-add-a-guard-ring-to-a-matrix-in-numpy#362576):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(range(9)).reshape((3,3))
>>> b = numpy.zeros(tuple(s+2 for s in a.shape), a.dtype)
>>> b[tuple(slice(1,-1) for s in a.shape)] = a
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Wanted to mention that at least with the version of NumPy (1.2.0 release) and Python (2.5.2) I have, the conversion to tuple is unnecessary and omitting it appeared to save time in my own limited testing. I forgot you could use slices like this!! Python is like the Feng Shui of programming.

Comment: And by 'omitting' I mean using [] instead of tuple(). Oops :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a less general but easier to understand version of [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362489/how-do-i-add-a-guard-ring-to-a-matrix-in-numpy#363040):

```
>>> a = numpy.array(range(9)).reshape((3,3))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b = numpy.zeros(a.shape + numpy.array(2), a.dtype)
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> b[1:-1,1:-1] = a
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is ancient now, but I just want to alert people finding it that [numpy has a function `pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) that very easily accomplishes this now.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(range(9)).reshape((3, 3))
a
Out[15]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

a = np.pad(a, pad_width=((1,1),(1,1)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
a
Out[16]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```